# Information from client to Textfile on Server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, screen-resolution, text-files

I have a code in javascript for Screen resolution , and I've put into an asp.net label using 
document.write("....") , then in C# got it using textbox.text = div.inneHTML

Now every thing works fine, but I want to get the resolution into a text file using C# 
and when I get it I'm getting the whole script "........." and no resolution like in the text box.

Below are the codes:

### ASPX Page

```
    <div id="vs" runat="server">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        document.write(screen.width + " x " + screen.height);
        </script>
</div>
<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Resolution With C# & JavaScript" Width="200px"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="res2" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Orange"></asp:Label>
```

### Code Behind "C#"

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    vs.Visible = false;
    res2.Text = vs.InnerHtml;

    string file_path = MapPath("log.txt");
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file_path, true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(vs.InnerHtml);
        sw.Close();
    }
```

My goal is to get the javascript variable to C# without a button, when the page is loaded only.

Comment: I agree, look at using a framework like jQuery to do something like that.

Comment: Please don't put C# in the title.  That is what the tags are for.

Comment: @Inuyasha -- on the contrary, this is one of the perfect times _to_ put something like "C#" in the title as it explains there is a client-->server path that isn't explained without it (from the title)

Comment: @cwolves: disagree. The tags provide that information, or it can be provided in the text. Titles are precious real estate. They need to attract readers to the question, not distract them with information available elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - the original title effectively said "can't get info from client->server", which was significantly more informative than it is now, especially considering that JS can't natively write a textfile (in general), so the title now makes the OP sound potentially incompetent :)

Comment: :)  Just making a point -- `C#` was as useful as `javascript` in the original title.  I think we go a bit overboard sometimes filtering stuff like that out because in 95% of cases it's superfluous.

Comment: i don't mind if jQuery is an option , i just want to have the result as i want it without a button :-)

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

why not use a hidden field...

markup

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden1" runat="server" />
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('hidden1').value = screen.width + " x " + screen.height;
```

code behind

```
sw.WriteLine(hidden1.Value);
```

Comment: i've tried this , but it's not working , actually it's witting an empty line , but when i put a button an give it "onclientclick" , then i get the second line with the resolution , but this is not what i want i just want it on page load ...

Comment: javascript runs on the client after the page on the server. take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885909/how-can-i-execute-javascript-function-before-page-load

Comment: i did it to my code , but i got the value = 1 and it was written in the text file as "1" , but i didn't got the value of javascript "screen resolution" , so any idea how ?
please give me the full code